# xcode project with apps in app

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, bundle, targets

I am somehow new to objective-c and iOS.
My question is as follows:
I have created 5 iphone apps until now. What I need now it to create a new project that will include all other applications in it. So the user would by 1 application and then from a uiviewcontroller he could launch the individual apps bundled in the application. Like an application bundle for the iphone. I have seen lots of this on the app store especially with games.
I have been searching for an answer for a week now. The only thing closely related that I found is related to targets, but how am I supposed to launch the individual targets from within the main app (if this is even possible).
Can someone please point me to the correct direction? A tutorial or an example would be great.
Thank you all in advance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check for any duplication in naming classes and resources in all your projects.  Since you want all your projects in one project, you have to eliminate duplication.
2. Copy the classes and resources to your new project (please keep things organised by using folders for your classes and resources).
3. Identify the root view controller of each app (where the app starts) call it from your new root view controller.

Comment: what about the things I do in every projects didfinishlaunching method? should I move them all to the bundle's delegate or to each project's root view controller?

Comment: I think it should be each project's root view controller.  But you might have to write extra lines of code or modify the code a bit where necessary as now you are not coding inside the delegate; mere copy paste might not work.

Comment: ok i did all that, but how am i going to implement the navigationbar and the tabbar that my apps use and which is the best way to call each application?

Comment: Call each sub project's root view controller from the new root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep every mini app separate, get rid of all of the app delegates when you copy them in. Each mini app needs its own way of launching, most probably through present modal view controller.

Just have the main app handle all the loading and app delegate stuff.